# Compare Temporary columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I'm not very good with VBA but I need a macro to compare two columns of data and if there is a match copy the value in the column next to the second column into another column.  for example:

```
A         B          C        D
123                  1234     222
1234                 123      567
1325
```

In this if A and C match then the value in column D in the same row as C will be copied over to column B in the matching row of column A.  A1 matches C2 so D2 gets copied to B1.

I understand this can be done using VLOOKUP however it won't stick if C and D are removed afterward which they need to be.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could C and D be hidden instead?

Comment: Hi NZaff -- I think your example didn't format correctly. Try putting four spaces before each line.

Comment: It's for a report that needs to be sent off.  I have tried hiding the data but it formats oddly on the other end.  Additionally using VLOOKUP also adds in it error output if there is no match which would need to be a blank cell afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring use of a different event handler this is my solution.

**Please note:** This is by no means an efficient script, files with thousands of rows may get bogged down by the number of loops within the tool.

**In a Nutshell Explanation:** There are two primary functions in this macro, the first does explicitly what you had been requesting. It searches C column for a matching value with a cell in A column. If there is a matching value, the value in the D column is copied to the appropriate cell in B column.

The second feature will notice if a Cell in C column does not have a matching cell and adds itself to the bottom of the A column. Since this is a separate loop, it can pe omitted without effecting the overall functionality.

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim CopyRow As Range, CopyRange As Range, SourceRow As Range, SourceRange As Range


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.EnableEvents = False


    'Sets last row used and ranges based on last row used
    i = 1
    While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    Set CopyRange = Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & i)

    x = 1
    While Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3) <> ""
        x = x + 1
    Wend
    Set SourceRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & x)

    'Compares every cell value in A column with C column.
    'If a value matches, copy the column from D to B
    For Each SourceRow In SourceRange
        For Each CopyRow In CopyRange
            If CopyRow = SourceRow Then
                SourceRow.Offset(, 1).Value = CopyRow.Offset(, 1).Value
            End If
        Next CopyRow
    Next SourceRow


    'Compares cells in A column with CElls in C column,
    'if a cell in C column is no present in A column,
    'then copy it and the value in D to A and B respectively.

    For Each CopyRow In CopyRange
    y = 0
        For Each SourceRow In SourceRange
            If CopyRow = SourceRow And CopyRow <> "" Then
                y = y + 1
            End If
        Next SourceRow
        If y = 0 Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = CopyRow.Value
            Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = CopyRow.Offset(, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next CopyRow

    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain how to change what columns it looks at and copies to and from?

Comment: Figured it out.  Thank you so much for this, I have been looking everywhere for a solution.